# Depending upon how I download, I get two different files

Tags: r

I am downloading the data set for the Kaggle competition on the titanic.

If I use the following code :

```
if (!file.exists("data")){
  dir.create("data")
}
fileUrl <- 'https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv'

download.file(fileUrl, destfile='./data/train.csv')
```

I get a 14kb file, however,
Paste [this Url](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv) directly in your browser and you will download the correct file about 60kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for sites where you don't need to be logged on. The Kaggle link only gives you the file when you are logged on to Kaggle. The file that is created with the code only contains html / javascript code of the Kaggle page.

Comment: As Kaggle requires you to agree to T&Cs before downloading, this is not going to be easy to work around.

Comment: phiver You are correct. I cannot download the data without logging in. How did you know that this code only works for cites where you do not  have to be logged on.